# No hungarian letters with UTF-8 encoding in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my Display datas from Mysql php page. My problem is when I want to display some hungarian specific chars like "á" or "é" they replaced with question marks. I set all of my tables and rows to utf8_hungarian_ci, and the entire table and rows to utf8_unicode_ci, but it doesn't work. A tried in my php code to set this "header(Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8)" at the beginning of my php code, but i haven't got any success with that. Can anybody help me? Thank you!
Edit: The code that I trying to use:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
function testfun()
{


$con=mysqli_connect('blabla");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM adatok");

echo "<table border='1'>";

$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if ($i == 0) {
      $i++;
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $value) {
      echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);


}
   testfun();

?>
```

Comment: add  <meta charset="UTF-8"> in your HTML code directly.

Comment: you have a syntax error and syntax highlighting is showing that. Mix of single and double quotes.

Comment: Guess that by now, you've worked out it was just a lack of the charset meta tag, and that maybe not have been a font supporting the Hungarian alphabet. üdvözlet gödöllőről!

Answer (score -1):

inside php tags use it this way
$stringTest = htmlentities("ésé");
Then inside html tags
use the variable

or simply use header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

Comment: It still doesn't work. :( Maybe I have problem with my database? I tried to display datas in c# and they appeared correctly on it. :/

Comment: <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?= "àè" ?>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Please use the above code and let me know whether u can see any output

Comment: The output is : Ã Ã¨